# How to prevent mobile keyboard (android) from messing up layout?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

My grid layout is being pushed up when you click on an `input` field, as pretty much everything is using `%` for `height` it makes sense, however is there anyway to stop it being messed up. I've tried using media queries to change the `.grid-container grid-template-rows` the only thing with this is that it would need to tested on a lot of phones to make sure it comes out correctly as needed.

Is there any solution through CSS or Jquery/JS?

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title>Blank App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./CSS/all.css">        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./CSS/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./CSS/messages.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./JS/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async=""></script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="topnav">
                        <a href="myShifts.html"><i class="fas fa-clock fa-3x fa-fw"></i></a>
                        <a href="timesheets.html"><i class="fas fa-edit fa-3x fa-fw"></i></a>
                        <a href="availability.html"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt fa-3x fa-fw"></i></a>
                        <a href="messages.html"><i class="fas fa-comments fa-3x fa-fw"></i></a>
                        <a href="accounts.html"><i class="fas fa-cog fa-3x fa-fw"></i></a>
                        <i class="fas fa-bars fa-3x fa-fw icon-float-right" id="sidenav-icon"></i>  
                        <div class="sidenav">
                            <a class="closebtn">&times;</a>
                            <a href="myShifts.html">
                                <div class="flex-container">
                                        <div class="item img"><i class="fas fa-clock fa-lg"></i></div>  
                                        <div class="item text">Shifts</div>                                     
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <a href="timesheets.html">
                                <div class="flex-container">
                                        <div class="item img"><i class="fas fa-edit fa-lg"></i></div>   
                                        <div class="item text">Timesheets</div>                                     
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <a href="availability.html">
                                <div class="flex-container">
                                        <div class="item img"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt fa-lg"></i></div>   
                                        <div class="item text">Availability</div>                                       
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <a href="messages.html">
                                <div class="flex-container">
                                        <div class="item img"><i class="fas fa-comments fa-lg"></i></div>   
                                        <div class="item text">Messages</div>                                       
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <a href="messages.html">
                                <div class="flex-container">
                                        <div class="item img"><i class="fas fa-cog fa-lg"></i></div>    
                                        <div class="item text">Settings</div>                                       
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>              
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="border-header">
                        <h3>NAME</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="msg-page">
                        <div class="messages" id="msg-list">
                            <div class="msg">
                                <div class="received">
                                    <div class="msg-header">
                                        <span class="time">13:24 | September 12</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="msg-body">
                                        <p>Text Msg HereText Msg HereText Msg HereText Msg Here</p>                 
                                    </div>                  
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="msg">
                                <div class="sent">
                                    <div class="msg-header">
                                        <span class="time">13:29 | September 12</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="msg-body">
                                        <p>Text Msg HereText Msg Here</p>                   
                                    </div>                  
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="msg">
                                <div class="received">
                                    <div class="msg-header">
                                        <span class="time">14:12 | September 12</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="msg-body">
                                        <p>Text Msg HereText Msg Here</p>                   
                                    </div>                  
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="msg">
                                <div class="received">
                                    <div class="msg-header">
                                        <span class="time">16:39 | September 14</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="msg-body">
                                        <p>Text Msg HereText Msg HereText Msg Here</p>                  
                                    </div>                  
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="msg">
                                <div class="received">
                                    <div class="msg-header">
                                        <span class="time">13:24 | September 12</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="msg-body">
                                        <p>Text Msg Here Text Msg Here Text Msg Here Text Msg Here Text Msg Here</p>                    
                                    </div>                  
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="msg">
                                <div class="sent">
                                    <div class="msg-header">
                                        <span class="time">13:29 | September 12</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="msg-body">
                                        <p>Text Msg HereText Msg HereText Msg Here</p>                  
                                    </div>                  
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="msg">
                                <div class="received">
                                    <div class="msg-header">
                                        <span class="time">14:12 | September 12</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="msg-body">
                                        <p>Text Msg Here</p>                    
                                    </div>                  
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="msg">
                                <div class="received">
                                    <div class="msg-header">
                                        <span class="time">16:39 | September 14</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="msg-body">
                                        <p>Text Msg HereText Msg Here</p>                   
                                    </div>                  
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="footer">
                        <textarea id="txtmsg-body" rows="3" placeholder="Enter message here.."></textarea>
                        <button id="msg-send">
                            <i class="fas fa-paper-plane fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
                        </button>   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./JS/main.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./JS/messages.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS Main:

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: default;
    outline: none;

/*
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
*/

    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
}

.col-1 { width: 8.33%; }
.col-2 { width: 16.66%; }
.col-3 { width: 25%; }
.col-4 { width: 33.33%; }
.col-5 { width: 41.66%; }
.col-6 { width: 50%; }
.col-7 { width: 58.33%; }
.col-8 { width: 66.66%; }
.col-9 { width: 75%; }
.col-10 { width: 83.33%; }
.col-11 { width: 91.66%; }
.col-12 { width: 100%; }

[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    /*padding: 15px;*/
}

.grid-container > .row:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

/* Using the new nav bar with icons instead of text */
.topnav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #0984e3;
    height: 100%;

/*  font-size: 0.9em;*/
}

.topnav > a, .topnav > i {
    color: white;
}

.topnav .sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #0984e3;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 60px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.topnav .sidenav.open {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.sidenav .flex-container {
    display: flex;
    align-content: flex-start;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.sidenav > a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidenav .flex-container .item {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 15px;
}

.sidenav .flex-container .item.img {
    width: 20%;
}

.sidenav .flex-container .item.text {
    width: 80%;
}

.topnav .sidenav .closebtn {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.border-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0.25px grey;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}

h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

.toggle-switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.toggle-switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

CSS Messages:

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    /* Might have to change this based on the current page as each page will have different row values */
    grid-template-rows: 8% 10% 75% 7%;
/*  grid-template-rows: 100%;*/
    height: 100%;
}
/*

@media screen and (max-height: 600px) {
    .grid-container {
        grid-template-rows: 12.25% 17.75% 57.75% 12.25%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-height: 400px) {
    .grid-container {
        grid-template-rows: 21% 20% auto 21%;
    }
}
*/

.message-container {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}

.message-container::after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
/*

.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0.25px grey;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
*/

.msg-page {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.messages {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.msg {
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
    color: white;
}

.msg::after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;    
}

.msg .received {
    background-color: #00b894;
}

.msg .sent {
    background-color: #0984e3;
    float: right;
}

.msg > div:first-child {
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 90%;
}

.msg .msg-body p {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.chats {
    padding: 5px 25px 5px 20px;
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
}

.received-msg {
    background-color: lightgray;    
}

.sent-msg {
    background-color: lightblue;
    right: 0px;
}

.footer {
    display: flex;
    box-shadow: 0px -2px 5px 0.25px grey;
    height: 100%;
}

.footer input[type=text] {
    width: 85%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.footer input[type=text]:focus {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* TODO: OUTLINE REMOVAL FROM MOST ELEMENTS ???? */
    outline: none;
}

.footer textarea {
    resize: none;
    border: none;
    width: 85%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 5vw;
    padding: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
    justify-content: center;
}

.footer button{
    width: 15%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: use flexbox for your CSS https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp had the same issue awhile back

Comment: @RubenMeiring do you mean replace the grid layout with flexbox layout instead?

Comment: Yes, replace your layout, containers  everything with flexbox, normal grid has always given me issues

Comment: @RubenMeiring could I just ask how exactly the flex layout make a difference in that sense? Seems like there should be something/some way of doing the grid layout correctly so that it doesn't cause issues for mobile input..

Comment: FlexBox is like it name says Flexible, grid layout gets like squashed and stretched etc. and looks out of porportion, Flexbox can get sqaushed and stretched etc but it keeps it porportionate